# Need to get results over 7 days that are in a specific 30 min time range :45 - :15 on the hour every hour

Tags: postgresql, psql

Hey guys I am a bit new to psql and need to gather some data that I not sure is possible.

So I have 7 days of data. The Columns are

user_id

import_date

range_1_99

range_100_149

range_150_199

range_200_249

range_250_up

I need to know how many times an action took place under

range_1_99

range_100_149

range_150_199

range_200_249

range_250_up

During a 30min window of :45 before the hour and :15 after the hour over 24 hours

So for example I want to report that

5 actions on range_1_99

10 on range_100_149

6 on range_150_199

0 on range_200_249

15 on range_250_up

happened between 09:45 - 10:15

and then the same for 10:45 - 11:15 etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ts_range,
    sum(range_1_99) as range_1_99,
    sum(range_100_149) as range_100_149,
    sum(range_150_199) as range_150_199,
    sum(range_200_249) as range_200_249,
    sum(range_250_up) as range_250_up
from
    t
    right join (
        select tsrange (
            date_trunc('hour', d) + interval '45 min',
            date_trunc('hour', d) + interval '75 min'
        ) as ts_range
        from generate_series (
            (select min(import_date) from t),
            (select max(import_date) from t),
            interval '1 hour'
        ) gs (d)
    ) r on import_date <@ ts_range
group by ts_range
```

Comment: and is t an alias ?

Comment: @JamesMadison: `t` is your table name.

Comment: Works great.. now just curious for my own purpose could I isolate down to the :16 to :44 time  its that like 16 min and then 44min

Comment: @JamesMadison: Could you post desired output?